# Difference between typed and untyped XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

Can anyone tell me the difference between typed and untyped XML in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Typed XML type have XML schemas to validate the Data where as Untyped XML type does not have schema.
2. Typed XML type has advantage of storage and query optimizations where as Untyped XML type does not have this advantage.
3. Typed XML types can be validated at both client side and Server side where as Untyped XML types does not have option to validate on server side as they do not have any schemas.
4. Typed XML types can take advantage of type information during compilations of queries.

Answer (score 3):

Beside the fact, that this is **really easy to find** with short research some points which come to my mind quickly:

The typed XML is **like a contract**: I promise, that you'll find XML-data of a given structure.

This is the base for XML indices, query optimizations and other fancy things.

The more SQL Server knows in advance, the better it will create its execution plans.

And very important: You will not be able to store different XML-structures in the same column.

So: If you know the structure in advance and you know that it won't change to often and you want to store the same kind of XML data in all rows of your table in this certain column, than type it.

One example here: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/interviews/show/583/what-is-typed-vs-untyped-xml-in-sql-server-explain-with-an-example

Comment: Good example.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Refer these: 
(It will give you an idea
)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184277.aspx

http://www.nullskull.com/faq/253/typed-xml-type-vs-untyped-xml-type-in-sql-server.aspx

Also, you can refer quora. I have seen this in quora.